# Spring Context is not updated SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication()

Tags: spring, spring-security

We have Spring Framework 4.1.0.RELEASE project. Our project is ingrated with third-party Service. Authentication is implemented through OAuth 2.0.

Our clients create some entity within our site and the entity is pushed to the third-party Service through Http request. Access tokens are expired periodically. Each request to the third-party Service
goes through checkAuthorization() method, which checks 401 Response, exchange a new token and replace old/new tokens. The access tokens is stored in

```
public HttpResponse checkAuthorization(HttpUriRequest httpUriRequest, String accessToken) {
HttpResponse response = tokenExchange(
clientId,
clientSecret,
refreshToken,
redirectUri
);
Json json = getJson(response);
String newAcceessToken = json.get("access_token");
ContextUser context = (ContextUser)oldAuth.getPrincipal();
context.setAccessesToken(newAcceessToken);
Authentication newAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
  context, oldAuth.getCredentials(), oldAuth.getAuthorities()
);
 SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth);
}
```

That process is working in the production site. But from time to time i encounter with that situation:

Several requests to the third-party Service has done with 401 Response within one minute. Differences are in milliseconds only. Corresponding request bodies are different. Requests are not the same. Each request in checkAuthorization() receives the same invalid token and each request update this token in checkAuthorization(). Despite of tokenExchange() was done with 200 Ok and the new token is set into ContextUser the next third-party request in checkAuthorization() receive the old token.

```
ContextUser context = (ContextUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

...
checkAuthorization(httpObject, context)
```

It is happen from time to time and in most cases it is working successfully. Third-party Service responded that no problem with their Service.

What is cause of this strange behaviour of updating access tokens?